# Login to Azure Active Directory programmatically

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, web-testing

I have a site (app) registered with Azure Active Directory.  I need my web tests to authenticate themselves (with a pre-existing testing user) at the start in order to obtain an auth token for the tests to hit the protected APIs.

What's the best way to accomplish this in C#?

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing something like below:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}")
    UserCredential userCredential = new UserCredential(userName, password);
    AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net/", clientId, userCredential);
```

Where `userName` and `password` are the user name and password of your test user. `authResult` has a member called `AccessToken` that can be passed to the methods you wish to test.

Comment: When I try this from a CLI test app, I get a "The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion" exception.

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846357/adal-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client-secret, I believe you can only use the approach I mentioned for native apps and not web apps.

Comment: how about in nodejs

Comment: What is client id?  Should be able to log in with just a username and password, just like on the portal.