# Sign in Webtest Oauth2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-testing

Using a full VS Enterprise to do some load testing against our WebApplication, I am struggling to create a webtest that works.
Our tested site is an Azure WebApp/API with an AAD authentication frontend. It is the authenticating as a test user that is failing. While recording with VS or fiddler, I'm failing to playback the test again. I believe it is a credentials/token issue...

As our app is not a Native one, I cannot get a token for a specific users credentials. (I'm getting a known exception)
I have succeeded in getting a Bearer token via the creation of a plugin and its PreWebtest method utilizing the code below however this is at application rather than specific user level.

```
private string GetAdToken(string inClientId, string inAppKey, string 
inAadInstance, string inTenant, string inToDoResourceId)
{
// inToDoResourceId = https://graph.microsoft.com
var myCredential = new ClientCredential(inClientId, inAppKey);
string myAuthority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
inAadInstance, inTenant);
var myAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(myAuthority);
Task<AuthenticationResult> myResults = 
myAuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(inToDoResourceId, myCredential);
return myResults.Result.AccessToken;
}
```

How can I achieve automation (via the web test) against a specific AAD test user identity to allow further testing automation of our web application?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: (1) How is `GetAdToken` called and with what parameters, i.e., from where are the parameter values acquired? (2) What does `AcquireTokenAsync` really do? Could (or should) it be done via another request within the test? (3) Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804066/how-to-set-up-the-jwt-token-before-the-vs-loadtest and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239972/visual-studio-web-performance-tests-oauth-2-0 for related ideas. (5) Please [edit] the question to add the missing details. As it stands you question seems to have insufficient detail for it to be answered.

Comment: The overload of AcquireTokenAsync() you are using does not take in any user-specific data (such as UserIdentifier, UserAssertion, ...) so it will not help you log in as a specific user.  Try another overload of AcquireTokenAsync().  However, you'll need to do the necessary steps to gather the proper arguments to feed to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found a solution to my problem: Cf. my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I found a solution to my problem:
there is a "Set Credentials" button in VS webtest tool where you can add your credentials. when i ran my test again, the test succeeded to sign in to my webapp.

@GuillaumeLaHaye, Yes I know that my AcquireTokenAsync() method was not user-specific but when Im using the one with UserCredential I was getting this exception: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.

because it is a WebbApp/API and not a Native App (configured in Azure Portal, cf. [ADAL: The request body must contain the following parameter: client_secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846357/adal-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client-secret))

@AdrianHHH, Get Ad token was called in a pugin in the preWebtest method (running before every test) with the clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AadInstance of my web App (I found them on my azure portal)... From this Oauth 2.0 flow, I believe I wanted to get the Authorization code or the access token, but because i'm new in webtesting and Authorization flow, I don't really know which token i got, neither how to use it...

[Oauth2.0 flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfR3Z.png)